# How to get out of this Catch 22 situation?

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I am having a Catch 22 issue that I cannot get out of, I am using UIAlertCOntroller to show information to the user and based on the answer I need to take some actions

```
if([NWTillHelper finishTransactionWithoutEmail] != 1) {
        if([NWTillHelper getCrmId] == nil) {
            //Step 1: Create a UIAlertController
            UIAlertController *userInfoCheck = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"No Customer Email!"
                                                                                   message: @"Do you want to proceed without customer email? No receipt will be sent out in this case!"
                                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            //Step 2: Create a UIAlertAction that can be added to the alert
            UIAlertAction *Yes = [UIAlertAction
                                  actionWithTitle:@"Yes"
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                  {
                                      NSUserDefaults *tillUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                                      [tillUserDefaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"finishTransactionWithoutEmail"];
                                      [tillUserDefaults synchronize];
                                      [userInfoCheck dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                  }];

            UIAlertAction *No = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"No"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                 {
                                     [userInfoCheck dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                 }];

            //Step 3: Add the UIAlertAction ok that we just created to our AlertController
            [userInfoCheck addAction: Yes];
            [userInfoCheck addAction: No];

            //Step 4: Present the alert to the user
            [self presentViewController:userInfoCheck animated:YES completion:nil];
            return;
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the last return statement seems to be run BEFORE the completion blocks finishes and I want the return to be conditional on the user action, but if I put the return in the Yes alertAction then the code below in the method is run before the user has the chance to select yes/no so I am stuck I need the last return to stop the code below that to be run but at the same time I need to wait for the completion block to finish? how can I handle this situation so that my code below this entire code block is run only after the user selects the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you see APIs that accept "handler" blocks, it's best to assume they run asynchronously. That means that the order of statements in your source code is not the order of operations.

In this case...

1. `presentViewController` returns immediately (and your function returns immediately thereafter), causing the alert to show.
2. The app continues to spin its main run loop while the user is sitting there looking at the alert box. UIKit tracks touches (even if they have no visible effect), other elements of your UI might be animating visibly behind the alert or reacting to non-user inputs like network activity (which may or may not involve other code of your own).
3. The user taps a button in the alert box, causing UIKit to run either your Yes or No completion handler.

This means that whatever logic you want to use for responding to the user's alert choice *cannot be written in the method body that presents the alert.* You'll need to arrange for such code to run as a result of your alert action handlers. A pseudocode-ish example:

```
- (void)handleEmailChoice:(BOOL)proceedWithoutEmail {
    // do whatever depends on user choice
}

// elsewhere
UIAlertController *userInfoCheck = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:/*...*/];
UIAlertAction *yes = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes"
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              {
                                 // set defaults, dismiss alert, then:
                                 [self handleEmailChoice:YES];
                              }];

UIAlertAction *no = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                                 // dismiss alert, then:
                                 [self handleEmailChoice:NO];
                             }];

[userInfoCheck addAction: yes];
[userInfoCheck addAction: no];
[self presentViewController:userInfoCheck animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to attach it to the root view controller, e.g.:

```
//Step 4: Present the alert to the user
UIViewController *controller = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
[controller presentViewController:userInfoCheck animated:YES completion:nil];
return;
```

Comment: Sorry exactly how does that help? Some more explanation would be nice

Comment: It might be that your `self` is being dismissed after the return, which destroys everything attached to it. The root view controller is more permanent.